# Formatting data with regular expressions?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, text-formatting

I wanted to format numbers all being exactly 8 digits long to to strings formatted like german date. E.g.

```
15081997 -> 15.08.1997
01012014 -> 01.01.2014
99999999 -> 99.99.9999
00000000 -> 00.00.0000
```

I tried cell formatting with `##.##.####`, but this format converts `15081997` to `15.081.997`.
So my two questions are:

- Is there a way to format my data only using these cell format thing?
- If not, are there formulas (`=FuncName(Params)`) that accept regulas expressions to format/extract/replace data?

Comment: If you wanted XX.YY.ZZZZ then why did you tell excel you wanted XX.YY.ZZ instead?

Comment: Sorry, little mistake. In excel I wrote `##.##.####`

Comment: `##-##-####` worked exactly how I expected it to. You won't be able to seperate the numbers using a `,` or `.` because they mean something specific to Excel. You can only have a single `,` in a formula by the way which is the reason your getting the grouping with your formula. For the purpose of this comment `,` is my thousands seperator `.` is your thousand seperator clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the periods:

> ##\.##\.####

This can be used as a custom format as you requested.

That should do the trick if I understand your question.

Comment: Yes, it works. I can't believe that I forgot the dot being this decimal point placeholder. I know the dot means an arbitrary character in regex, but I didn't think about a special meaning in formats, so I forgot to escape it :D